# Sum IF Query for Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table for every month that has a column I need to add. I need to make a query to show it all in one table. First thing I did was to union all tables to get the unique Countries. How do I configure this ms access query that I started to produce the output i need?

Example Tables:

Table 1: January 2014

```
 | Country | Headcount |
 |   USA   |    100    |
 |  China  |     50    |
 |  Russia |     75    |
 |   USA   |     10    |
```

Table 2: February 2014

```
 | Country | Headcount |
 |   USA   |    100    |
 |  China  |     50    |
 |  Mexico |     100   |
 |  China  |     75    |
```

Table 3: All Countries

```
 | Country |
 |   USA   |
 |  China  |
 |  Mexico |
 |  Russia |
```

Desired Output:

```
 | Country | January   |  February  |
 |   USA   |    110    |  100       |
 |  China  |    50     |  125       |
 |  Russia |     75    |  0         |
 |  Mexico |     0     |  100       |
```

This is my query so far but it doesn't seem to work..

```
SELECT a.[Country] As Country, 
SUM(IIF(a.[Country] = b.[Country], b.[Headcount],0)) As January 
SUM(IIF(a.[Country] = c.[Country], c.[Headcount],0)) As February
FROM [All Countries] As a, 
(SELECT [Headcount], [Country] FROM [January 2014]) As b,
(SELECT [Headcount], [Country] FROM [February 2014]) As c
GROUP BY a.[Country]
```

Comment: Can I know why I got a markdown?

Comment: Do you have any primary key in your tables ?

Comment: added `sql-server` tag based on the identifiers using `[...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach that should work -- (edited)

```
    SELECT a.[Country] As Country, 
SUM(IIF(a.[Month] = "Jan", b.[Headcount],0)) As January 
SUM(IIF(a.[Month] = "Feb", c.[Headcount],0)) As February

FROM     (
SELECT [Headcount], [Country], "Jan" AS [Month] FROM [January 2014]
 UNION ALL
SELECT [Headcount], [Country], 'Feb' AS [Month]  FROM [February 2014]
UNION ALL
...
) AS a
GROUP BY a.[Country]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this :

```
SELECT a.country,
(SELECT SUM(b.headcount) FROM table1 b WHERE b.country = a.country) as january, 
(SELECT SUM(c.headcount) FROM table2 c WHERE c.country = a.country)as february
FROM countries a

GROUP BY a.`country`
```